# Is algebra: ac=ca, bd = db , ad - da = cb - bc ("Manin matrix algebra") - a Koszul algebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, koszul-duality, koszul-algebras

**Question:** Consider quadratic algebra with four generators $a,b,c,d,d$ and three relations $ac=ca,bd = db, ad-da = cb - bc$ . Is it a Koszul algebra ? (i.e. Koszul complex is resolution of ground field $k$).   (Checking algebra is Koszul, is something algorithmic or more kind of creative task ? )

**Context:** The relations above first appeared in [Yuri Manin's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Manin) papers on "Noncommuative geometry and quantum groups" (around 1986-7). And define "[Manin matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manin_matrix)", in the simplest 2x2 case it looks like that, consider 2x2 matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$
The relations above ensure that despite non-commutativity - such matrices behave like commutative ones - one can define the determinant: $ad-cb$ , it will be multiplicative, Cramer's inversion formula works, Cayley-Hamilton, MacMahon, Newton, etc ... "all" linear algebra statements - holds true in such a relaxed commutativity setup.

**Generalizations, applications:** There are many applications to representation theory of loop algebras - explicit description of central elements, local Langlands GL-oper, [Capelli's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capelli%27s_identity),  etc. See e.g. A. Molev's lectures: https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/alexm/talks/seoul-manin.pdf

The question above have various generalizations - we can consider not 2x2 Manin matrices, but $n\times m$ with generators $M_{ij}$, q-analogues, super-analogues, [Manin matrices of types B, C, D](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-229),  generalization to other [qudratic algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.05993), modifications for [algebras with involution](https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.19300) and so on. And ask the same question - whether  obtained algebras are Koszul. At least when underlying algebra is Koszul.

In particular one the questions - mentioned in A.Molev's lectures (see page 261/78) - for the super-Manin matrices we do not know the Hilbert series and basis generating the algebra. Koszulity might help on that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly Theorem 4.1.1 of [https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~vallette/Operads.pdf](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Evallette/Operads.pdf) then the answer is "yes".

I'll take the order $a<b<c<d$ and use lex ordering like they do. Then the leading terms of the relations you list are $ba, dc, da$. In particular, there are no critical monomials, so the theorem automatically applies.

I hesitate here because this seems a bit too easy, but I guess the intuition here is that there are "few relations which don't interact too much" so you get a well-behaved algebra.

**EDIT**: I did a little more exploration of this example. The observation above also says the 3 relations are a Gröbner basis, so we can compute the Hilbert series by just working with the Koszul algebra $A$ whose relations are the monomials $ba, dc, da$. I can model this as words in $a,b,c,d$ with the following rule: if you see $b$, the very next letter is not $a$, and if you see $d$, the very next letter is not $a$ or $c$.

In particular, words of length $n$ are the same as walks of length $n$ in the directed graph starting at vertex 1 with the following adjacency matrix
$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$
(the convention here is that the entry in row $i$ and column $j$ is the number of arrows from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$). To elaborate: the walk is reading the letters as input and vertex 2 means we just saw $b$ and vertex 3 means we just saw $d$. Anyway, the transfer matrix method then tells us that the Hilbert series is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-4t+3t^2}$.

That also implies that the resolution of the residue field has finite length and looks like:

$0 \to A(-2)^3 \to A(-1)^4 \to A$

(the notation $(-i)$ means grading shift by $i$).

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Quick remark/more quest:  consider q-Manin: ca = q ac; db = q bd  ; ad − da = q^{−1}cb − q bc ;   consider q->0. We get: ca = 0; db = 0; cb = 0. Is it rue:  that this algebra have same Hilbert series ? May be  your arguments about Grobner basis  and " whose relations are the monomials ba,dc,da" - are similar to such a limit (or q->infinity) ? Does it follow from the same arguments that such limit is also Koszul ? Or it is not true ?

Comment: Yes to all.

A quadratic algebra defined by monomials is always Koszul (Theorem 4.3.6 of above reference). Since those relations are a Gröbner basis, the limit will have the same Hilbert series as the original algebra.

Comment: Thanks again ! A somewhat open-ended question. Manin constrution is kind of non-commutative Endmorphisms of  (in that case) polynomial algebra and exterior algebra. So naively  it is a kind of "tensor" product of these two... So naively Hilbert series might be expected to be related to product of the polynoms and exterior. Any kind of interpretation of that type ?

Comment: Can the Koszul dual algebra be described by some kind of "nice"  generators/relations ? As far as I understand choice of "nice" generators/relations for dual algebra - not always are dual generators ? Or I am wrong - it typical examples "nice" description - just take dual geneators/relations ?

Comment: I don't know about your tensor product question.

As for the dual: if $R$ is the span of your relations in $V \otimes V$ for your original algebra, then the dual is canonically defined as the tensor algebra on $V^*$ modulo the quadratic relations $R^\perp$, which is the annihilator of $R$. The dual algebra is pretty small though: it vanishes in degrees 3 and higher.

Comment: Thanks a lot a again ! If it would be possible to write down the dual algebra relations explictly - that would be great ! As far I understand (1-4t+3t^2) is its Hilbert series - so 4 generators and degrees are 1,2. Can that be written in something like Cartier-Foata form - https://mathoverflow.net/a/467348/10446 ? that would  mean that relations like ab=0 are also admittebly in Cartier-Foata formulas...