GAP cannot solve Rubik's cube 4x4x4 and higher ? (Practical limits of Schreier–Sims algorithm)
According to our practical experiments and literature search -  computer algebra system GAP cannot "solve" Rubik's cube 4x4x4 and higher. That means cannot decompose given random element of the permutation group into the product of generators,
if the group is large enough - like 10ˆ45 elements - Rubik's cube 4x4x4. (Assuming  standard CPU machine with say RAM 32G).
Question 1: Is that correct ? (Or there are some tricks to make it work known to experts) ?
GAP is based on Schreier–Sims algorithm which description of complexity might be sort of confusing - see previous MO discussions collected here: on the one hand it is kind of polynomial complexity, but according to the cited discussions it can produce exponentially long decomposition lengths (it is also explicitly stated in the paper "Planning and learning in permutation groups": "are usually exponentially long").
Question 2: What can be said more precisely about complexity of Schreier–Sims algorithms - not using "O" notation, but giving some precise constant which would correspond to practical implementations in systems like GAP ?
Question 3: How does the polynomial complexity coexist with exponentially long outputs ?
Is it due to the fact that algorithm first creates strong generating set which contains elements of the form like $sˆk$, for very large "k" ? I.e. to compute "k" one needs polynomial, but we should take value of polynomial at $|G|$, not $log|G|$ ? Or there is some other mechanism ?
PS
Here is an example from  GAP tutorial to handle  the standard 3x3x3 Rubik's cube:
https://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/homes/GAP/WWW2/Doc/Examples/rubik.html

What... is... GAP?

@HelloGoodbye https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAP_(computer_algebra_system)

Thank... you...!

No, that is not at all correct. GAP easily can solve $n\times n\times n$ cubes for say $n\leq 50$ (and probably quite a bit beyond).
For $n=4$, the naive permutation degree is $6\cdot4^2=96$. There are no special tricks to make it work. My guess would be that you made a mistake somewhere, but it is hard to say without seeing your code.
The group order is usually not the limiting factor at all. We routinely work with groups much larger than $10^{45}$. The permutation degree and the minimal size of a basis are much more important.
The diameter of the Rubik's cube group for $n=4$ won't be high. My guesstimate would be that a typical random element would have an expression with $<100$, or at least in the order of magnitude. So no problem with any "exponential output size" here.
Maybe what you are thinking about is finding guaranteed shortest decompositions. That is indeed much harder, and not something Schreier-Sims is made for. But that's not at all needed to solve the cube, which is what you are asking about.

Just found https://mathoverflow.net/a/322109/8338 which suggests that a 4x4x4 cube can be solved with at most 55 moves, so my guesstimate seems about right (allowing for some leeway for not-quite-but-close-to-optimal solutions found by Schreier-Sims)

https://arxiv.org/abs/2404.07337 diameter for 4x4x4 conjectured to be 48 recently.

About phenomena of "exponential length" - it is NOT about diameter, it is about the fact you get short writing in terms of strong generating set - but elements of strong generating set can be quite longly written - see e.g. Derek Holt's post here https://mathoverflow.net/a/474713/10446 , at least it is what I understand

Nevertheless I know people whi regularly hand out Rubik cube variants of all kinds of sizes to their students and ask them to solve then with help Schreier-Sins and they cope quite well

Can you share any example please with 4x4x4 cube ? Or at least what lenghts of output you would expect ? Note: for 3x3x3 tutorial examples outputs are about 100, that is far from optimality - worse than humans.

Many colleagues tried to use GAP at recent data Science challenge on the Kaggle platform - where the task was precisely to decompose given elements https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023 but there were no successful case reported - more than 1200 participants.

I am not sure what you are trying to say here. There were 1200 participants to that competition and clearly many managed to solve it. Whether they used Schreier-Sims or not doesn't seem to be recorded. That you know a handful of colleagues who struggled to find any solution using Schreier-Sims is sad, but I don't see any evidence that nobody managed to do it. In any case, I also don't think you'd have a chance to win this contest with pure Schreier-Sims, because it is about minimizing the solutions. But again, that's not what you asked about.

First thank you for your answer and comments, second I am now searching for these notebooks where GAP was failed to solve anything except 3x3x3, but it is late here and i might find them tomorrow only. Meanwhile if you can provide code with examples solving 4x4x4 cubes - would be very kind of you. if you need explictly given generators: they are in the following file https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/data?select=puzzle_info.csv . Any way would appreciate your help to find out what is going on .

It seems to access this data I need to sign up with Kaggle (which requires agreeing to all kind of data tracking) and then "join the competition". I am not willing to do that. I'll see if I can find the generators elsewhere or generate them from scratch

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexandervc/growth-in-finite-groups/data?select=puzzle_info.csv From here - should not require any kind of  "sign up".
Droping you an email - please take a look

Here is attempt to solve 444 cube - it fails trying to allocate more than 330(!!) Gigabytes memory available on Kaggle TPU machine: https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/group-theory-via-gap-part-1/notebook?scriptVersionId=209162984 and log with message error
https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/group-theory-via-gap-part-1/log?scriptVersionId=209162984 . The code is used the same as from 333 GAP cube tutorial. In the other version - attempts with CPU machine with 32 Gigabytes RAM - same RAM problems

Here is examples of SAGE code which every one can insert even in web sagecell or cocalc and check it will not produce any results (while for 333 everything is Ok): https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexandervc/growth-in-finite-groups/discussion/547862

After discussion with some experts - what you probably mean by "GAP easily can ... " concerns basic Schreier–Sims algorithm - which makes a test - element is in subgroup or not. That test has polynomial complexity - mentioned e.g. in Wikipedia. But the decomposition of the elements - has exponential complexity and as tests above show  GAP cannot solve even 444 cube, at least out-of-box.

Any chance to get feedback ? The experiments above show - GAP cannot solve 444, we conducted more experiments with other groups - big groups are beyond GAP abilities.
